# Exception "Your version of PHP... is affected by CVE-2013-6420..." when creating Laravel project

Tags: laravel-5, openssl, composer-php

On running the command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

I am getting these errors -

```
Your version of PHP, 5.4.12, is affected by CVE-2013-6420 and cannot safely perform
certificate validation, we strongly suggest you upgrade.


 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
 The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded:
 SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
 error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
 Failed to enable crypto
 failed to open stream: operation failed

 create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] 
 [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url           
 REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] 
 [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--noprogress] [--keep-vcs] 
 [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>][<version>]
```

Can anyone please tell me what may be the problem. I am using a proxy network. In environment variable I have set both http_proxy & https_proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For laravel 5.2 minimum version of php required is 5.5.9
So you have to upgrade your php version.
Also you need to have only http_proxy as system variable if you are using proxy network, not the https_proxy variable.

Comment: This error went away when I `unset HTTPS_PROXY`, thanks!